# Javascript - How do I play a lot of sounds without memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm making something with javascript that's going to require a lot of sounds to play.

Here's my code for playing sounds:

```js
var playsound = function() {
soundthing = document.createElement('audio');
soundthing.setAttribute('src', 'http://mylegguy.x10.mx/GmsJs/happy.wav');
soundthing.play();
}
playsound();
```

After playing a few hundred of the same sound, I get the "something went wrong" message on Google Chrome. I can see the memory going up and up as more sounds are played.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't memory leak, if it does, it seems like an error in Chrome. But, I would definitely only create the `<audio>` element only once, outside your play function and then re-use it over and over.

Comment: Yes, creating an audio element every time you call the function is definitely a mistake. I'm surprised that it leaks a significant amount of memory, but there's probably some reason that the browser can't just store the audio data once if it's referenced from multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 audio-API:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

**//HTML**

```
<div class="lg-12">
          <audio id="player" controls="controls">
            <source id="sourceOgg" src="" type="audio/ogg" />
            <source id="sourceMp3" src="" type="audio/mp3" />
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
          </audio>
        </div>
```

**//SCRIPT**

```
function loadSong(){

    var player=document.getElementById('player');
    sourceMp3.src='my-song.wav';

    player.load(); //just start buffering (preload)
    playSong();
}

function playSong(){
    player.play(); //start playing
}
```

Comment: How do I play the two of the same sound at once with this? Make two of the player?